# Why the result of 'java.beans.PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(targetType)' is null

Tags: java, reflection

I have registered the "EntityEditor", the result of "PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(...)" should be EntityEditor. But actually the result is null, I'm quite confused about this. Anyone can help?

I use Oracle Java1.8 on MacOS-10.

```
import java.beans.PropertyEditor;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorManager;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;

.......
.......

@Test
public void test3() {
    PropertyEditorManager.registerEditor(Entity.class, EntityEditor.class);
    PropertyEditor editor = PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(Entity.class);
}

static class EntityEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Entity entity = new Entity(text);
        setValue(entity);
    }
}

static class Entity {
    private String desc;

    public Entity(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the `EntityEditor` class visibility to `public`.

Comment: @yegodm It works, thanks